# Visual Studio 2013 Dark Theme for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

After searching for several hours, I was unable to find a completely implemented theme for VS2010 that replicates the look of the VS2013 Dark Theme (A few people were close, but I couldn't get Properties, Solution Explorer, Output, Error List, and a few other windows to change colors as well).

I was wondering if someone knew of a theme that is the same as VS2013 Dark Theme, or if someone could possibly create it! I know of several people where I work that would utilize this theme.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: If you -1 please let me know why in a comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378) extension in Visual Studio 2010 and apply a pre-defined theme or create your own theme.

Comment: "I was wondering if someone knew of a theme that is the same as VS2013 Dark Theme, or if someone could possibly create it!" This was the question I wanted answered, not what to download to be able to create it myself. I have attempted creating it myself.